# jList - Add element and show String?

Tags: java, swing, list, compiler-errors, jlist

what's up?

I created one jList on my project that I can't retrieve the element. I know jList only accepts objects, but I was adding Strings to my list, because when I add "Discipline" object, I see something like "***Discipline{id=21, name=DisciplineName}***" on my view. So, I'm adding strings instead objects.

Following is my code:

```
ArrayList<Discipline> query = myController.select();
for (Discipline temp : query){
    model.addElement(temp.getNome());
}
```

When I get the index of a double click in one element, I try to retrieve my String to make a query and know what's this discipline. But I'm getting some errors, **see what I already tried**:

```
Object discipline = lista1.get(index); 
// Error: local variable lista1 is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final

String nameDiscipline = (String) lista1.get(index);
// Error: local variable lista1 is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
```

I really don't know what means "final", but what can I do to solve this problem? One thing that I thinked is:

#### Can I add a Discipline instead String, show to user discipline.getName() and retrieve Discipline object?

Comment: The error message is telling you what you have to do: make lista1 and index `final`

Comment: Often it is better to solve the error by making the JList a field of the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, add Discipline objects. A quick fix is to change Discipline's toString method, but a much better fix is to create a ListCellRenderer that displays each Discipline's data in a nice String.

Here are two ListCellRenderers that I have used in a project of mine to change the item displayed in my JList from text to an ImageIcon:

```
private class ImgListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

  @Override
  public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
        int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
     if (value != null) {
        BufferedImage img = ((SimpleTnWrapper) value).getTnImage();

        value = new ImageIcon(img); // *** change value parameter to an ImageIcon 
     }
     return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index,
           isSelected, cellHasFocus);
  }

}

private class NonImgCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
  @Override
  public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
        int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

     // all this does is use the item held by the list, here value
     // to extract a String that I want to display
     if (value != null) {
        SimpleTnWrapper simpleTn = (SimpleTnWrapper) value;
        String displayString = simpleTn.getImgHref().getImgHref();
        displayString = displayString.substring(displayString.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);

        value = displayString;  // change the value parameter to the String ******
     }
     return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index,
           isSelected, cellHasFocus);
  }      
}
```

They are declared like so:

```
private ListCellRenderer imgRenderer = new ImgListCellRenderer();
private ListCellRenderer nonImgRenderer = new NonImgCellRenderer();
```

And I use them thusly:

```
  imgList.setCellRenderer(imgRenderer);
```

The DefaultListCellRenderer is pretty powerful and knows how to display a String or an ImageIcon correctly (since it is based off of a JLabel).

Comment: How can I create a ListCellRenderer, can you show me a piece of code?

Comment: @FernandoPaladini: yep, have a look at the [JList Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for sample code.

Comment: Thanks. I will try solve this problem and when I fix that, I think I will give you the best answer. Thanks!!

Comment: @FernandoPaladini: I posted two private class ListCellRenderers that I've used that extend DefaultListCellRenderer, a handy class to use. A bit of the code is of course specific for my application but hopefully you'll get the general idea. Please ask if any questions.

Comment: Why when you set Cell Renderer, you call your extend code by "imgRenderer"?

Comment: @FernandoPaladini: oops, I forgot to show where I declared the variables. Please see edit. But you'll likely only need to create and use one ListCellRenderer, likely extended from DefaultCellRenderer.

Comment: Ok, now just a newbie question: can I rename the "NonImageCellRenderer" or you're overriding a existent class?

Comment: +1, but @FernandoPaladini, just be warned that by using a custom renderer you break the default behaviour of a JList (or JCombobox). That is you can no longer select an item in the list by entering the first character of the rendered value. The default implementation uses the toString() value for this. Depending on your requirement this may, or may not, be an issue.

Comment: @camickr: true, true, but I base my recommendation based on what kleopatra/Jeanette recommends. In my mind (and in hers) `toString()` should be used for debugging purposes and not for end-product display purposes. I suppose this could be gotten around by using a wrapper object whose sole purpose was to create a `toString()` override. Thoughts?

Comment: Ok, thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels and camickr. I will give you the best answer. Again, thanks!

Comment: I agree, in general, toString() should not be for end-product display. I don't have a problem with a wrapper class, whose reason for existing is to have a toString() implementation for end-product display (Jeanette does). My concern is application functionality. A GUI is built for a user. A User doesn't know one component uses a custom renderer and another doesn't.  I just want a warning any time the renderer approach is used that it breaks default functionality.

Comment: Thanks @camickr and Hovercraft! I will use toString(), but now I will learn about CellRenderer (because in the future I will need use this)